# how to set help utility for my own command in batchfile?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to know that how can i set help utility in my own batch file command. I am using windows 7 operating system. we can check the syntax of command in windows command promt by just typing

```
help "command name"
```

like

```
help attrib
```

so i have created batch file which takes path/folder name as argument and setting it as hidden and system file. The code has three line

```
@echo off
attrib %1 +s +h
echo File/Folder hide successfully...
```

i saved it as "hide.bat" at C:\windows\system32 so i can use it from any directory. But i want to know that how can i set help utility for my command. i want to display

```
attrib [file/folder name] +s +h
+ to set an attribute
```

when user type

```
help hide
```

hide is my command name(batch file name)

I have changed my code to display help content when user pass blank argument

```
@echo off
IF ["%1"]==[""] goto showhelp
goto done

:done
attrib "%1" +s +h
echo File/Folder hide successfully...
goto close

:showhelp
echo attrib [file/folder name] +s +h
echo + to set an attribute

:close
```

But it is not enough for me i want to display my help content when user type

```
help hide
```

so tell me how can i set it?

Comment: I doubt, that it's possible to add another command to `help` without debugging/patching `help.exe` But there is the `/?`parameter with almost any program, and you can easily build it into your batchfile. Just add a line `IF "%1"=="/?" goto showhelp`

Comment: @Stephan: You can't patch help.exe. It's one of the Windows built-ins (in the System32 folder), and Windows would just replace it if you did so.

Comment: Exactly. And even if it **would** work - this would be a solution for this one and only Computer - not very helpful. Therefore implementing `/?` is the common way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Save this as `help.bat` and put it a folder that is earlier in the PATH than the `\windows\system32` folder.

There may be an earlier folder already - type `set path` and look at the folders before system32 - or you can add one yourself.

```
@echo off
if /i "%~1"=="hide" (
   echo attrib [file/folder name] +s +h
   echo + to set an attribute
  ) else (
   "%Windir%\system32\help" %*
)
```

Comment: That's not "adding my help information to help.exe", which is what the question asked. This may make it *appear* that help supports your batch file, but it does not answer the question asked. It only works if you alter the entire system PATH.

Comment: @kenwhite this covers it pretty well `i want to display my help content when user type help hide`

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive I tried this one. But its not working for me. I am getting this "This command is not supported by the help utility.  Try "hide /?"

Comment: Which folder did you put the batch file in?  Did you type 'set path' in a cmd window and pick a folder that is shown before it lists `c:\windows\system32` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add your own content to `help`. It's an executable file  (`help.exe`) that's part of Windows itself. It's located in the Windows System32 directory. It only knows about certain applications or commands that are built into the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`).

Unless you want to write a full replacement for it, you can't alter it or the programs it knows.

Comment: There is a workaround though, Ken.  See my answer - @stephan also.

Comment: @foxidrive: That's not what the question asked. See my comment to your "answer".

Comment: That's funny, I can read this without any trouble `i want to display my help content when user type help hide`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
if /i "%1"=="" ( echo "Nothing Entered"
)
if /i "%1"=="help" ( echo "Help text"
)
```

just use help after the command rather than in front of it and the solution is as simple as^